# Call to undefined function factory()

Tags: laravel, testing, factory, lumen

*Environment: Laravel Framework Lumen (8.2.2) (Laravel Components ^8.0)*

When I run

`$blogs = factory('App\Blog', 2)->create();`

in `BlogsControllerTest.php`, it shows

**Call to undefined function factory()**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Laravel's [upgrade guide](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/upgrade#model-factories) says the Model factory was changed.
The new way is like this `App\Models\Blog::factory()->count(3)->create();`

To use old version referrer to [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/upgrade#model-factories).

> However, to ease the upgrade process, a new laravel/legacy-factories package has been created to continue using your existing factories with Laravel 8.x

To install it use composer `composer require laravel/legacy-factories`

Comment: Thank you for your answer.

When I run 
```App\Models\Blog::factory()->count(3)->create();```

Show this:
```BadMethodCallException: Call to undefined method App\Models\Blog::factory()```

Comment: You need to use `use HasFactory;` in your model.
So in your `Blog` model, first import it from here
 `use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;`

Then in the model `use HasFactory;`

Comment: The `use HasFactory;` works. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question in case it helps somebody.

It works this way too.

`$blogs = BlogFactory::new()->count(2)->create();`

ref: [laravel.com/docs/8.x/database-testing#connecting-factories-and-models](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/database-testing#connecting-factories-and-models)